# Compose the value of a field based on values of other fields with Freeform plugin

Tags: plugin-freeform, freeform

Is it possible to create a hidden field which is composed by the values of previous fields?

Example:
Field A: First name
Field B: Last Name

Hidden Field automatically composes the values: "First name" & "Last name"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job the [Preparse plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/preparse-field?craft4) could do.